# xelatex: command not found

Tags: texshop, mac

I upgraded my Mac to the OS X EI Capitan a few days ago. And now TeXShop is not working. When I try to typeset it, the console shows the following error:

`xelatex: command not found.`

Following a previous answer, I went to `Preferences-->Engine` and changed the path of (pdf)TeX from
`/usr/texbin`
to
`/Library/TeX/texbin`

But the error was still the same.

Then, I also tried to change accordingly the path for the Distiller ghostscript from
`/usr/local/bin`
to
`/Library/TeX/local/bin`

But still, all remains the same.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I re-downloaded MacTex (from https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) and now it works. I checked the path under Preferences--»Engine and the distiller has now the same path I had manually inserted, namely:
/Library/TeX/local/bin
Thus, I still do not know why it did not work, but at least it does now;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the engine path to `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin`. It works for me, although I have tested it throughly.